# Is there any way to derive parameters of a stored procedure in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, sqlclient, .net-standard-2.0

`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` is not available in .net core (even in .NETCoreApp 2.0), so is there any way to retrieve the parameter list of a stored procedure in .net core?

Comment: It will be available in netstandard 2.1,https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/20883

Comment: I'm playing around with its daily build. Thank god, it works perfectly with my code

Answer (score 0):

You could always just inspect the SQL Server catalog views to get this information - for example, with this query:

```
SELECT  
    pr.name,     -- Procedure name
    pa.name,     -- Parameter name
    pa.parameter_id,
    ty.name,     -- Parameter datatype name 
    pa.max_length,    -- Max length (of string parameters)
    pa.precision,     -- Precision (total num of digits) for numeric parameters
    pa.scale,         -- Scale (num of digits after decimal point) for numeric parameters
    pa.is_output,            
    pa.has_default_value,    
    pa.is_readonly,
    pa.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN 
    sys.parameters pa ON pa.object_id = pr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON ty.user_type_id = pa.user_type_id
```

This can be extended - there are quite a few more bits of information around, if you're interested in those.

See [SQL Server catalog views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql) for a great deal more information and detail about the indispensible catalog views in SQL Server

Comment: Due to the policies in our company, the sql-account, which is used in web code, does not have permission to access those system's objects (procedures, parameters, types, etc.). And we have many database servers, so that it's not a good choice to create a stored procedure with your suggested t-sql and deploy to all DB server. Then do we have any way to do it in web code (cry)

Comment: *Then do we have any way to do it in web code (cry)* - no, unfortunately, this information is stored **inside SQL Server** and accessible via these catalog views. If you cannot inspect those, you're pretty much out of luck, I'm afraid.....

Comment: I just wonder how `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` (full .net framewok) deals with it. And is there any problem to port it to .net standard? We are porting some of our libraries to .net core, but seem it's not an easy work :(